# Firebase App Indexing test Failing while Firebase API is called

Tags: android, firebase, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

[image]

Please view the above image. I am using the Firebase App Indexing test for my Android app. I have followed the official App Indexing tutorial, but still, I am getting this error.

Things I have done:

1. Implemented Firebase App Indexing API in project. (I can see logs,
   this is working fine.)
2. Updated assetlinks,json file in .wellknown directory. (3 days ago)
3. Enabled Deep Linking in app (Working fine)

Please suggest what can be the possible reason or if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Some questions:

1. Your assetlinks.json file -- is it available on https ? Per https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/public-content
2. Have you checked your AndroidManifest.xml to see if the links are correctly set up?
3. Are you running on a device, and not the emulator?

Comment: 1. Yes, the assetlinks.json is available on https
2. Deep links are working correctly
3. Yes I am running on device.
4. However, I am yet to publish app to playstore.